# Transform SDP Optimization Constraints

Tags: convex-optimization

A problem of the form was hinted at on an upcoming assignment:

$minimize$ $tr(P)$ 
 $s.t.$ 
 $A^TP+PA = -Q$, 
$P=P^T>0$

 It was hinted that the desired solution require the problem be transformed into a form similar to the one shown below and solved via KKT optimality conditions. Where the transformed constraints will be four equalities or inequalities.

$minimize$ $(C^TX)$ 
 $s.t.$ 
 $AX = b$

My question is how are these four transformed constraints found or derived?

---update---
Perhaps I am over complicating this. If $A$, $Q$ and $P$ are $2x2$, that would be four linear equalities of the form $Ax=b$. For $P=\begin{bmatrix}p_1&p_3\\p_3&p_2\end{bmatrix}$, would it be valid specify the problem as $minimize(p_1+p_2)$, since we want to minimize $trace(P)$? Then taking the 1st equality piecewise:

$(1)$ $2A_{11}p_1+2A_{21}p_3=-Q_{11}$
$(2)$ $A_{12}p_1+A_{21}p_2+(A_{11}p_1+A_{22})p_3=0$
$(3)$ $2A_{22}p_2+2A_{12}p_3=-Q_{22}$

And to define P as PSD:
$(4)$ $p_1 \geq 0$
$(5)$ $p_1p_2-p_3^2 \geq 0$

Then apply the KKT conditions to $min(p_1+p_2)$ and constraints 1-5, treating $p_1, p_2$ & $p_3$ as the variables for which to be solved?

If that is the case, why did the instructor hint that the problem should be transformed to $minimize(C^TX)$?

Comment: why do you call the constraints of the original problem *quadratic*?

Comment: Are they not? Isn't the Lyapunov equality usually associated with the form $x^TPx$?

Comment: That's irrelevant to the immediate task at hand. The point is your problem in $P$ already has a linear objective, a set of linear equations in $P$, and a semidefinite constraint.

Comment: $C^{T}X$ is a matrix rather than a scalar- are you actually meant to be minimizing $\mbox{tr}(C^{T}X)$?

Comment: Michael Grant, I think I understand. Are you saying that everything is already correct for applying KKT, similar to what I added to the original question?

Comment: $C^TX$ is a scalar. If $X$ is vector of length $n$, then $C$ is a vector of length $n$ such that $C^TX=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (C_kX_k)$